# Why will echo -e "test" print "-e test"?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The "-e" option in "echo" means that support escape sequences. However, I found it would output "-e" instead.

I have written a shell script and run it to get an "-e" result. And I have typed the same command on my `zsh` interactive shell, and I got an ideal result.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo -e "test"
```

I expect the output to be `test`, but the actual output is `-e test`.

Comment: Closely related, see the excellent answer by Stephane on the [unix.se] question [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Standard `echo` doesn't support any arguments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/echo.html):

> OPTIONS
>   The echo utility shall not recognize the "--" argument in the manner specified by Guideline 10 of XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines; "--" shall be recognized as a string operand.
>
> Implementations shall not support any options.

Then again, backslash-escapes are either undefined, or (in XSI-complient systems) expanded.

The actual implementations differ. Bash's `echo` doesn't expand backslash-escapes, except with the `-e` switch. Dash (Debian's and Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`) expands them, and doesn't know about `-e`. Zsh also expands them by default, but recognizes (and ignores) the `-e`, and has `-E` to *disable* expanding backslash-escapes.

To be on a safer side, use `printf` instead.

Comment: @ikkachu, it doesn't say they *should* be supported, it says they *may* be supported, if the shell chooses to implement optional XSI extensions. For baseline POSIX, output when any literal backslashes are present on the argument list is simply undefined.

Answer (score 2):

> The "-e" option in "echo" means that support escape sequences.

That depends on which `echo` you're using, the one built into your shell (and if so, which shell) or the `/bin/echo` executable. It's not portable.

Apparently your `/bin/sh` doesn't support the `-e` option in `echo` .

Comment: Not just which shell, what the active runtime flags to that shell are. Enable `xpg_echo` in bash (at compile time, or via the environment variable flags, or via a `shopt` operation) and its behavior suddenly changes.

Answer (score 1):

I bet when you do `ls -la /bin/sh` it is a symlink to `dash`.

```
$> dash -c 'echo -e test'
-e test

$> dash -c '/bin/echo -e test'
test
```

Comment: That may or may not be true, and doesn't explain *why* `sh` being `dash` would make a difference.

Comment: (For example, `/bin/sh` is `bash` on macOS, but it's not a link--hard or symbolic--to `/bin/bash`.)